# 'DeltaTable' object has no attribute 'optimize'

Tags: azure-databricks, delta-lake

I am trying to compact the delta table in Databricks, but for some reason, it fails to execute optimize command on delta table and shows the below error.

Can someone please tell me what is the issue here?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a reference: from delta.tables import *

Comment: Yes I did that, giving the issue still

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're using Delta Lake version before 1.2.0. Per [documentation](https://docs.delta.io/latest/optimizations-oss.html#optimize-performance-with-file-management&language-python):

> This feature is available in Delta Lake 1.2.0 and above.

Comment: How do I find which version I am using?

Comment: you can check with either `pip show delta-spark`

Comment: I'm getting this error after running pip. Does that mean that showing version is disabled on my end? `CalledProcessError: Command 'pip --disable-pip-version-check show delta-spark' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: what is the databricks runtime version?